# Getting Python os.listdir() to pass full file as argument

Tags: python

I am trying to use `os.listdir()` to get a list of all the files within a specific directory as it is intended. I point the function to the directory and it obtains the file list as I want it to, but when I pass the list of files to the function I want to call it only passes the file names, not the full path. Is it as simple as appending the path to the file name within the function call? Here is what I have now as far as passing it to the function:

```
listPos = os.listdir("C:/Users/User/Desktop/prog3_data/trainingdata/pos")
listNeg = os.listdir("C:/Users/User/Desktop/prog3_data/trainingdata/neg")

for file in listPos:
    with open(file) as filePos:
        print (fcount(filePos))
```

So do you think it would work if I wrote it like:

```
listPos = os.listdir("C:/Users/User/Desktop/prog3_data/trainingdata/pos")
listNeg = os.listdir("C:/Users/User/Desktop/prog3_data/trainingdata/neg")

for file in listPos:
    with open(file) as filePos:
        print (fcount("C:/Users/User/Desktop/prog3_data/trainingdata/pos" + filePos))
```

I don't have a compiler on this computer so I need to know if this sounds reasonable on paper.

Comment: Yes, that is how it works. Ideally, use `os.path.join('C:/...', filePos)` to get the system-specific delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listPos = os.listdir("C:/Users/User/Desktop/prog3_data/trainingdata/pos")
listNeg = os.listdir("C:/Users/User/Desktop/prog3_data/trainingdata/neg")

for file in listPos:
    with open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/prog3_data/trainingdata/pos/" + file) as filePos:
        print (fcount(filePos))
```

Nevermind, I figured it out...